# Probability of employees absence

Tags: probability, independence

Given: On average one employee is absent 12 days per year (365 days). There are 5 employees in a company. It is assumed, that the absence of one employee has no effect on the others, and there is no seasonality.

Question 1: What is the probability that all 5 employees will be absent on the same day?

Question 2: What is the probability that at least 3 employees will be present on the same day?

Are the following answers correct?

$P(All 5 Absent)=(12/365)^5$

$P(At Least 3 Present)=(1-12/365)^3$

Comment: Your answer to (1) assumes independence and uniform probabilities over the year and that you are only considering a particular day (January 20 for example).  Your answer to (2) is wrong.

Comment: Thank you, Henry. For (1), is it still correct to say that everyday within a year the probability will be the same (12/365)^5?

Comment: For (1) that is the probability for each day if you make the assumptions I suggested

Comment: For the second problem, consider cases:  exactly three employees are present, exactly four employees are present, exactly five employees are present.  You need to consider both the probability that $k$ employees are present and the probability that the other $5 - k$ employees are absent.

Comment: Thank you, N. F. Taussig and Henry,

**First approach:**

$$P(\text{exactly 3 out of 5 present})=\binom{5}{3}*(1-12/365)^3*(12/365)^{5-3}$$

Where: $\binom{5}{3}=\frac{5!}{3!(5-3)!}$

$$P(\text{exactly 4 out of 5 present})=\binom{5}{4}*(1-12/365)^4*(12/365)^{5-4}$$

$$P(\text{exactly 5 out of 5 present})=\binom{5}{5}*(1-12/365)^5*(12/365)^{5-5}$$

$$P(\text{at least 3 out of 5 present})=P(\text{exactly 3 out of 5 present})+P(\text{exactly 4 out of 5 present})+P(\text{exactly 5 out of 5 present})$$

Comment: **Second approach:**

$$P(\text{at least 3 out of 5 present})=1-P(\text{all absent})-P(\text{exactly 1 out of 5 present})-P(\text{exactly 2 out of 5 present})$$

Where $$P(\text{all absent})=(12/365)^5$$

Am I correct now?

Comment: I would appreciate any feedback that can help me understand if my new solutions to Question 2 are correct.
P.S. Yes, I assumed independence and uniform probabilities over the year.